# How to reorder the Dataframe data in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
      0   1    2
0  2016   0    5
1  2018   0  167
2  2017  28   54
3  2019   4  271
4  2020  10  111
```

I want to reorder the above above Data Frame like below

```
      0   1    2
0  2016   5    0
1  2018   167  0
2  2017  54   28
3  2019  271  4
4  2020  111  10
```

Comment: It would help the OP improve his question and learn if the downvoter explained here.

Answer (score 0):

Select and assign,

```
df[['1', '2']] = df[['2', '1']]
```

Or Reorder and rename the columns

```
new_order = ['0', '2', '1']
df[new_order].rename(columns=dict(zip(new_order, df.columns)))
```

Or use a temporary variable which is simple to understand

```
temp = df['1'].copy()
df['1'] = df['2']
df['2'] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.rename` method.

```py
df.rename(columns = {'1':'2', '2':'1'}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: You need to sort columns after that